# Is it a good practice to minimize the number of the activities in the application to minimize the number of possible memory leaks?

Tags: android, memory-leaks

In an Android application,

Is it a good practice to minimize the number of the activities in the application to minimize the number of possible memory leaks?

For example, we use just one activity instead of 2 so as to prevent memory leaks at least when switching to the other activity

Answer (score 2):

No.  If you want to prevent memory leaks, look for and fix memory leaks.  Use Leak Canary or similar tools.  Reducing the number of Activities to try and fix it is kind of pointless-  Activities don't cause memory leaks.  Bad programming does, and if you're making those kind of mistakes you'll make them regardless of the number of activities you have.

Comment: So since I have just 1 activity then I don't see any memory leaks from leak canary and in fact I have some leaks there and they are detected just when the screen rotates and if I don't rotate the screen I never see any leaks from the leak canary

Comment: So try and determine what the leaks are.  Most likely, you're holding a reference to your activity in either a thread or in a static variable.  This includes any mechanism that may use a thread, like RxJava

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand yet, compare when there is a reference just to 1 activity and there is a reference to 2 activities, which one is worse? in other word when an activity has memory leak, the problem is the reference to that activity still remains and if you have leakage somewhere else in the same activity, then you have still reference to the same activity remained (which previously you had for the first leak) and nothing more but when there are 2 activities you will have reference to 2 activities remained instead of one